# Will a DisplayObject be garbage collected if its reference is set to null, but it's not removed from the display list?

Tags: actionscript-3

Will a `DisplayObject` be garbage collected if **the only reference keeping it in memory** is set to `null`, but it's not removed from the display list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is in a display list, there are still references to it in the system.

Comment: Alas, it is necessary to remove the child when destroying it.

I ran a test, myself, and found my container's 'numChildren' property to reflect the nullified object still being on the display list.

Comment: +1. Just a note: if you have chain of `DisplayObject` instances (a parent with children) that is detached from the `Stage`, then those objects *can* be garbage collected as long as there are no references from the system.